# TrySetDisableLayoutScaling not working

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

For a specific device app , I have to build Xaml Pages with some png .
So I need to disable scaling .
trySetDisableLayoutScaling is supposed to do the job since 10.0.14393.0

But it returns false and nothing change.

Help me :)

Comment: Try to create a [MCVE], or at least post some code snippets.

Comment: It's just one line call to this api  : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewscaling.trysetdisablelayoutscaling.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ViewBox on every Page solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

To preserve the physical size of UI, Windows automatically scales UI elements. You might not want this behavior, for how to counteract the automatic scaling of text and UI elements, you can reference [this official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DpiScaling) to reset your `UIElement` to what you want manually.

For [`TrySetDisableLayoutScaling`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewscaling.trysetdisablelayoutscaling.aspx), as it is  for 'trying', it may be fail. This method seems like to prefer used in [XBOX application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/disable-scaling).